# What is the best way follow to player with camera?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I started to learn Unity3d two days ago, so I am beginner in Unity. I try to follow to player with camera, it works but player is shaking when moving. Here is my Camera and Player move scripts.

```
public class CameraFollow : MonoBehavior 
{
     public Transform player;

     void update()
     {
          transform.position = new Vector3(player.position.x, player.position.y + 15, player.position.z - 3);
     }
}

public class PlayerMove : MonoBehavior 
{
     public float speed = 5f;

     void update()
     {
          transform.Translate(0f, 0f, Time.deltaTime * speed);
     }
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid there's no `best way`... You haven't provided any real context, so it's too broad and opinionated as it stands at the moment... Btw, it's usually a bad idea to update player's position using Translate.. But that as well depends on the requirements and specific situation.

Comment: I understand. I was work in 2d engines(cocos2d, sprite-kit .etc) but I am new in Unity3D. What is your suggestion for player movement?

Comment: Depends on the context, type of the game, what effect are you trying to achieve etc...

Comment: I am trying to achieve 3d Endless runner game like (temple run, subway surfers .etc).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of having two movement scripts, delete the cameraFollow script, then put the Camera inside the Player's object. When the player moves/rotates, the camera will move and rotate accordingly, but will stay at the exact same location relative to the player, thus the player doesn't move in the camera.

So, place the camera inside the player's object, then change it's coordinates so that the camera is at the correct location.

Comment: the coords should be x:0, y:15, z:-3 according to your code.

Answer (score 0):

I have pivotObject as root object. And every frame move it to player position.

Then i attach a cameraObject to it with coordinates (0, 10, 0).

So now, when i want to rotate camera, i rotate pivotObject.
And when i want to set distance from player to camera, i col cameraObject.Normalise().Scale(x)

To prevent falling camera throw walls, i use Physics.SphereCast(...)